# LED viewing angle for POV display

Tags: led

Would you rather use LED with 30° or 140° viewing angle for Persistence of Vision display? I will have two columns (each column one color) of 16 LED, columns are very close to each other, cca. 0.1mm. Both LEDs have same mcd rating.

As I am restricted by current coming from the battery I could use only 2mA forward current LEDs, these LEDs have a typical 400mcd for green and 100mcd for red. Would you say that is enough bright? I really don't have any clue how do they look in reality based on mcd ratings.

Most importantly I would like to know how much is viewing angle important in this type of application ie. POV display.

Comment: I guess viewing angle depends on where you want it to be seen from and brightness for POV depends on the ambient brightness (i.e. if ambient is to bright in relation to LEDs, the "persist" part of POV doesnt work.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 30° will work much better than 140°.

The viewing angle includes half the total luminous flux (mcd).

If the mcd remains the same for both LEDs the 30° LED will appear 4.6 times brighter than the 140° LED when viewed straight on.  140/30 = 4.666